# codeigniter dropdown select data from database

Tags: codeigniter

```
<select class="form-control">
            <?php
              $flag=0;
              foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

              if(flag==0)
              {
                 <option value="<?php echo $row->tbl_group_id; selected="selected"?>" ><?php echo $row->tbl_group_rolename; ?></option>
               flag=1;
               }
               else
               {
                 <option value="<?php echo $row->tbl_group_id;?>" ><?php echo $row->tbl_group_rolename; ?></option>
                }
              } ?>

                <option value="name">One</option>
                <option value="email">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
                <option value="four">Four</option>
                <option value="five">Five</option>
            </select>
```

I have one dropdownbox(on login page) in which I have to get all the data from my database and it must be shown dynamically.

My form is created in bootstrap way.
I want all the data to come from table, dynamically in dropdown and when I select it; I can register as that person for example admin/user.

I have tried nothing till now; nothing comes in my mind.

Comment: There are a lot of misplaced PHP start and end tags in your code.

Comment: i know just i want to add dynamic values in between option tag so please do not consider php formatting at this time.thank you

Comment: This is not about formatting, your code simply **does not work** if you do not place the start and end tags at the right position.

Comment: oky sir i will. is there any answer regarding this??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to fix your PHP start and end tags. This is necessary because otherwise the PHP interpreter does not know what to evaluate.

The rest is pretty straightforward. I changed your `$flag` to a boolean in order to check whether the current entry is the first entry and therefore should be selected. Also I removed the duplicated code and introduced an `if` that outputs `selected="selected"` for the first option.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <?php
    $first=true; // Used to select the first element
    foreach ($result as $row): /* everything between here and 'endforeach' is part of the loop */ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->tbl_group_id ?>" <?php if ($first) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>
            <?php echo $row->tbl_group_rolename ?>
        </option>
        <?php if ($first) $first = false /* this makes sure that only one option element is selected */ ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <option value="name">One</option>
    <option value="email">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

The loop iterates over the rows. Note that the colon after the foreach statement uses an alternative syntax that makes it easier to read if mixed with HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
    <!-- HTML code here that gets printed once for each $row -->
<?php endforeach ?>
```

You then put some PHP code inside the HTML to make it dynamic.

```
<?php if ($first) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>
```

The code above prints `selected="selected"` if `$first` is true. After the first iteration `$first` becomes false:

```
<?php if ($first) $first = false ?>
```

Comment: what changes should i have to make in my controller, model and view

Comment: I cannot tell you unless you show some of your code. Edit your question and post the relevant code.

Comment: Great, please consider sharing your solution as an answer so that anyone who was the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select class="form-control">
        <?php
          foreach ($result as $row) {
            $sel = ($row->tbl_group_id == $someId)?'selected="selected"':'';
          ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->tbl_group_id;?>" <?php echo $sel; ?> ><?php echo $row->tbl_group_rolename; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>    

            <option value="name">One</option>
            <option value="email">Two</option>
            <option value="three">Three</option>
            <option value="four">Four</option>
            <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
```